# Two line Tab Text

Tags: c#, winforms, text, tabs, multiline

I've seen this done in Visual Basic (though I haven't seen the code, or how it is done in design view, if that is possible). Is there way to create a *two-line **tab name*** in WinForms? Please see attached picture, I've circled it for emphasis. Surely, there must be a way to do it. In fact the attached picture is done in VB6, which unfortunately I have no access to the code.

Note: If this is a bad idea or not a good practice, please let me know. Also if the solution is too complicated and not worth exploring, I am open to abandoning it, but if it is simple enough, that would help me a lot.

I'm running out of *prime* real estate on the screen, as some of our forms have 12 tabs on them (it can't be helped), and our screens are limited to a maximum of 1280 x 720. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Unfortunately I am not allowed to post a picture, i.e. this is my first post. If that helps, I will post them somewhere else where it is possible.

Maybe this edit will help for the moment, (sorry for the poor illustration, it's the best I can do given the (posting) editor limitations):

---

| Tab | Tab  | Tab |
|No.1 | No.2| No.3|

---

The above **tab labels (text)** should have two lines on the tab names, e.g. ***Tab 1 No. 1, Tab 2 No. 2***, etc. where *Tab 1* is on the first line, and *No. 1* is on the second line...etc.

Here's the image link:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRPQ2.jpg

Comment: so where is the attached Image..? just curious..

Comment: @MethodMan, the user does not have the rep to embed the image, but could include the link so someone can edit it into the question if appropriate.

Comment: You may be interested in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.multiline.aspx) property.

Comment: I agree @Alex that would also help

Comment: @ Grant Winney, you're right, I should say WinForms. As mentioned, I am a newbie and pardon my inaccurate terminologies. @ MethodMan, Alex is right, but unfortunately, most websites that allows me to post an image is blocked by our organization. Still looking for one and will post it as soon as possible.

Comment: If you want the tab text itself to be multiline, this might work: `myTabControl.TabPages(0).Text = "Foo\nBar";` I.e. insert a newline to force wrapping.

Comment: @GrantWinney The OP did not specify it should still be readable :D But I agree it is a hack and Blorgbeard's solution makes more sense.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, the property you mentioned is for creating a multiline tabs, which can be done at design time in VS by setting the multiline property to true. i was looking for multiline (text) label on a single tab. thanks for all the replies...but i'm still waiting for a working solution.

Comment: @wzk I know, it's not exactly what you want - just thought you might not know about it, and it might have been a good alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The full solution is spread over the `TabControl` and its `TabPages`.

To enforce a `NewLine` you insert a `\n` in the `TabPage`'s `Text`.

```
tabPage1.Text = "Line one\nLine two";
```

Note that you need **code** to set the `Text`. Setting it in the `Designer` won't work! (It takes the `Backslash` literally instead of as an escape sequence and since it only offers a single line field you can't use `Shift-Enter` either..)

You still can use the designer, but will have to enforce the `newline` in code, maybe like this:

```
tabPage1.Text = tabPage1.Text.Replace("\\n", "\n");
```

Or, bettter, in a loop:

```
foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages) tp.Text = tp.Text.Replace("\\n", "\n");
```

To make enough room you enlarge the `Tab`'s `ItemSize.Height` to say 40 to 48 pixels, of course depending also on the `Font`!:

```
tabControl1.ItemSize = new Size(tabControl1.ItemSize.Width,  42);
```

Result:

[image]

Note that the inactive `TabPage`'s `Texts'` descenders tend to be cut off at the `Bottom` unless you make the height really large. If that's a problem, I guess you would have to 'owner-draw' the `TabControl`.Sounds harder than it is..:

Set the Tabcontrol to owner draw:

```
tabControl1.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
```

and add this piece of code to the DrawItem event:

```
private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ( e.Index == tabControl1.SelectedIndex)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
    else
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Control, e.Bounds);

    TabPage tp = tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index];

    Point pt = new Point(e.Bounds.X + 2, e.Bounds.Y + 4);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(tp.Text, tabControl1.Font, SystemBrushes.ControlText, pt);
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

This is a real space saver; the height is down to 34 pixels resulting in this:

[image]

One of the nice things is that now you could show the the active page with its backcolor in the tab, too, that is if you have different backcolors for your pages..

Note however, that since the System doesn't know what you will do in the DrawItem code, it will reserve enough room for the whole, unsplit text, resulting in too broad tabs.  You can fix this, if you want to, by storing the real `Text` in the `Tag` of each page and making the `Text` only as long as needed for the longest line:

```
if (tp.Tag == null)
{
   tp.Tag = tp.Text;
   tp.Text = "_____________";  // make large enough!!
}
string s = tp.Tag.ToString();
```

and use `string s` in the `DrawString` call!

If you want to make it perfect you can write a function to measure each `TabPage Text` and its line break position to find out the necessary width..

[image]

Comment: \n, \r\n or Enviroment.NewLine does not seem to work with the Text on the tabPage1 (in this example). Am I missing something obvious here? I am thinking there is no multiline property for this tabPage1.Text?

Comment: Not sure how you wrote it or which option you are using. One thing though: You need to set the Text __in code__ in one of the two ways I now mention  in the updated answer.. Un, no, not really obvious, I just never noticed, sorry!

Comment: This is great! And thanks again for sharing this code. I've got everything working, just this part here is what I am trying to figure out: _One of the nice things is that now you could show the the active page with its backcolor in the tab, too, that is if you have different backcolors for your pages_ My understanding on this statement is that you can make the tabControl the same color as the background color of the tab which is set on the BackColor property on the designer?

Comment: Yes, I like to do that sometimes. If the tabpages have individual Backcolors, this color will not by itself spread up into the tab and the page and its tab will not look as one as they should. By using a SolidBursh created form tp.Backcolor instead of SystemBrushes.Window it'll look like one piece. Of course it only makes sense if you have individual colors for the pages. In your case of a rather crowded tab control I guess I wouldn't do it..

Comment: would you be kind enough to give more details on how to let the color spread into the tab and the page? I cannot figure this part out. Thanks in advance. If it helps, I've included the full code based on your examples above.

Comment: would you be kind enough to give more details on how to let the color spread into the tab and the page? I cannot figure this part out. Thanks in advance.  <br/><br/> 
...
            InitializeComponent();
            tabPage1.Text = tabPage1.Text.Replace("\\n", "\n");
...
      }
        private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
 ...
            {
            tp.Text = "Line1\nLine2";  // make large enough!!
            }
            //set the back color of the tab
            tp.BackColor = Color.Maroon; //this is not working
        }

Comment: Here is what I meant: If you have set background colors to the tabpages, it would be nice to show that color at least in the tab of the active page. To do so you must simply replace: `e.Graphics.FillRectangle( SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);` with something like this: `using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(tp.BackColor) )  e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);`. Note that this will only work if the TabPages actually __have __a Backcolor set! Those that don't will show up Black, so you need to either set the BackColor for all pages or check for `(tp.Backcolor != Color.Transparent)`

Comment: only owner draw works for me (.net 4.0 winform), but still great answer

Comment: only own draw works for me, but still great answer