# How to change height of TabPage?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I wanted to ask how can I change the distance between TabPages and TabControl in Windows Form applications. I'm pointing to the area which should get a bigger distance.

[image: tabcontrol]

Comment: Check the [TabControl.ItemSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.itemsize?view=netframework-4.8) and [TabControl.SizeMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.sizemode?view=netframework-4.8) properties.

Comment: There is nothing built-in but you can either work on the [TabHeight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955580/two-line-tab-text/29965707#29965707) or add a spacer Panel, docked Top to the TabPages, best in a subclass..